# JavaScript: Testing for undefined throws var is not defined error...?

Tags: javascript, undefined

This is an oddity I've seen occasionally in JS - maybe someone can shed light on it.

I do a test for undefined on a variable:

```
if (x !== 'undefined'){}
```

or even

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined'){}
```

And the browser still throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Even

```
if (x) {}
```

throws the error.

This is a framework-level global variable I am checking for, so possibly something to do with different scopes.  (No critiques of global variables - again, its the existence of a framework I'm testing for).

Comment: second one - `typeof x !== 'undefined'` should not throw a ReferenceError.

Comment: Which browser/version are you working on ?

Comment: Anurag: exactly - shouldn't but does

Comment: Not possible: all major browsers support this correctly and never throw an error for `typeof x` for any `x`.

Comment: can you post a reproducible example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? also what is the configuration (browser/version/os) that it's occurring on if it  makes a difference.

Comment: For some reason IE9 threw for me, which lead me here in search of WTF is going on... Hard-refreshing the page worked, but I can't explain it. I am inclined to blame IE...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's pretty weird. What about:

```
if (window['x']) {
   // It's defined
}
```

Does the above work? Also, what browser or JavaScript interpreter is this?

Comment: The problem appears to be crossbrowser (IE/FF/Safari).  Using the window['x'] actually works, I can test for !window['x'] without error.  Somehow, the browser is testing x in one scope and erroring out in another.

Comment: Want to add, even this method not worked, but window.x worked -_- , really weird.

Comment: See also the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581470/the-use-of-undefined-variables-in-if-statements): "You'll have to define it, to be able to check it for a value." Maybe that should read: You'll have to _declare_ it, to be able to check it for a value. `if(variable)` actually checks for a value and also works to check for possibly non-existing _properties_: `if(obj.variable)`. If a 'naked' variable might not be declared, its existance can safely be checked with `if (typeof(variable) == "undefined")`.

Answer (score 5):

@Anurag is right the second condition should not through error.

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined'){// won't through error even if x is not declared
}
```

I guess the problem is that x is not declared as a variable. If you declare it but leave it unassigned it is treated as undefined and won't through error, in your case it is not declared.

```
var x;
if (x !== undefined){// won't through error
}
```

Objects fields are treated differently

```
if(window.x !== undefined){// won't through error

}
```

it seems like x in this case is declared in runtime if not found,
so returns undefined

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess the important part here is the window.x !==undefined which i always use. It is okay to check for undefined in the window object, since they always are "declared" when someone checks for them...  But that is not applicable to a normal scope though.

Comment: @Miguel Overuse of that approach(3rd) will spoil the app with global variables which is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `undefined !== 'undefined'`

Comment: But `typeof x === 'undefined'` ;)

Comment: Fast typing response error xD. I see your point now. As @anurag and @timDown said in FF 20.0.1 you don't get errors with `typeof x !== 'undefined'`. Good luck testing other browsers